# Cannot select Kubernetes version in portal UI or via CLI

Tags: azure-container-service

I'm trying to create a new Kubernetes cluster using the Azure portal. In both the portal and CLI I am unable to retrieve any Kubernetes versions. In the portal UI, the dropdown for versions is empty. Via cli I receive a 404:

```
az aks get-versions -l centralus
```

> Operation failed with status: 'Not Found'. Details: Subscription {REDACTED-GUID} could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft support provided me an answer to this question. My account did not have the Microsoft Container Service enabled. It can be enabled via the command:

```
az provider register -n Microsoft.ContainerService
```